# Why won't my site's icon show up in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, icons, favicon

I'm trying to get my site's icon to show up in Google Chrome, but am stumped as to why it's not. It works in IE, FF, Opera, and Safari. Here's the icon-related  code currently on the page:

```
<LINK REL="apple-touch-icon" HREF="/_images/icons/BHS2.2 - Modern 512.png" TYPE="image/png" />
<LINK REL="shortcut icon"    HREF="/_images/icons/BHS2.2 - Modern.ico"     TYPE="image/x-icon" />
<LINK REL="favicon"          HREF="/_images/icons/BHS2.2 - Modern.ico"     TYPE="image/x-icon" />
```

The actual page is at [BHStudios.org](http://bhstudios.org/) in case you want the full sauce. I don't want any tangents about site design, just the icon.

Comment: Fixed, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Thanks, tho!

Comment: Well, that's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: Did you try with a no-spaces url for your icon?

Comment: Have you tried this `HREF="/_images/icons/BHS2.2%20-%20Modern.ico"` i.e. using %20 in place of the spaces?

Comment: Your favicon is also extraordinarily large at over 400kb.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert as I told @DavidStetler, the `.ico` file contains 256, 128, 64, 48, 32, 24, 16, and 8-pixel square images

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above? On a side note, it is best practice to write html in lower case rather than the upper case you have used.

Comment: @tw16 Thanks, but I asked for no tangents about site design, and I hope to include coding practices with that

Comment: I brought it up because if you take a look at your code validity: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbhstudios.org%2F you can see that you have a number of errors in the head of your document, which is obviously where the favicon is declared. So I wondered whether you might have some invalid characters etc. and I found the upper case characters reduced the readability of your code as I tried to spot the issues.

Comment: Strange, I find that using uppercase improves readability because it helps me distinguish HTML from other languages used int he documents.

Comment: HTML text changed to lowercase, didn't change anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the name to favicon.ico and move it to the root of the site.

Comment: The `.ico` file contains 256, 128, 64, 48, 32, 24, 16, and 8-pixel square images

Comment: have you tried renaming to favicon.ico, and then removing all the links except:  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

Comment: The apple-touch-icon is required for Opera's Speed Dial and some touch device apps, so I can't remove that. I'll try renaming

Comment: I just meant remove for testing, I would maybe try listing the apple-touch-icon link second.

Comment: Done! Moving it to the root and renaming it `favicon.ico` fixed it. Submit it as an answer so I can accept it :3

Answer (score 0):

after a google search, i've found this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_images/icons/BHS2.2 - Modern.ico"  type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/_images/icons/BHS2.2 - Modern.ico"  type="image/x-icon" />
```

please try and tell me if it worked.